# Error in Jest with NEXT/IMAGE: Invalid src prop on `next/image`, hostname "res.cloudinary.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`

Tags: jestjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I did some tests with img and it was perfectly fine, but when I added the next/image this error was generated, and even with the next.config.js file configured, the error persists.

```
Invalid src prop (https://res.cloudinary.com/dezwlfeyb/image/upload/v1635633843/Contabilidade-Smart-negativo-172_e5oyxn.png) on `next/image`, hostname "res.cloudinary.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

  10 |   ui: ReactElement,
  11 |   { ...renderOptions }: CustomRenderProps = {}
> 12 | ) => render(<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{ui}</ThemeProvider>, renderOptions)
```

next.config.js

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

    module.exports = withPWA({
      pwa: {
        dest: 'public',
        disable: !isProd
      },
      images: {
        domains: ['localhost', 'res.cloudinary.com']
      }
    })
```